# Inequality on unsigned values

Tags: c, unsigned, comparison-operators, inequality

I have always wondered about the following situation.

Let `L_1 > L_2` be unsigned values (in this case `size_t`). Also `A` is of the same type.

Will this test work:

```
if( A > (L_1 - L_2) )
{
    //  do stuff
}
```

or is it equivalent to

```
if( 0 > (L_1 - L_2) - A )
{
    //  do stuff
}
```

or

```
if( 0 < A - (L_1 - L_2) )
{
    //  do stuff
}
```

which simplifies to

```
if(!(A - (L_1 - L_2) ))
{
    //  do stuff
}
```

Since everything is `unsigned`. The last thing will "do stuff" as soon as `A != L_1 - L2`, which is not what I want.

Comment: which you under stand better?

Comment: `!(A - (L_1 - L_2) )` != `A > (L_1 - L_2)`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: Why? Give me a proof of contradiction.

Comment: I am wrong as I didn't read `L_1 > L_2 be unsigned values`, and `A` also unsigned ??

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: yes A is unsigned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know there are plenty of values for which`A > (L_1 - L_2)` is true.
For example, with `L_1 == L_2` and `A == UINT_MAX`.

But `0 > (L_1 - L_2) - A` is always false. As `L1`, `L2` and `A` are unsigned operands `(L_1 - L_2) - A` is an unsigned expression. The value of an unsigned expression  is always `>= 0`.

Comment: Is the problem that I already assert that A > (L_1 - L_2) and therefore, i cannot subtract A from both sides?

Comment: @user877329 The algebraic equivalences with relational operators no longer hold with unsigned operands because of their wraparound behavior when the algebraic result is not representable in the unsigned type.

Comment: so i do not risk that the expression is true expect when A != L_1 - L2

Comment: If what I described holds then I cannot test for greater than since it becomes equivalent with true in most cases

Comment: @user877329 I don't understand what is your question, please reformulate

Comment: I was wondering if test goes through in all cases expect when A!=L_1 - L_2

Comment: @user877329 as you can read in my answer, no. In the example in the answer, we have `A != L_1 - L_2` and `A > (L_1 - L_2)` but `0 > (L_1 - L_2) - A` is false.